# Cumulative Sum with Multiple Criteria

Tags: r, dataframe, cumsum

I am trying to get a cumulative sum from a big table.
This is rather difficult for me to explain in words, but I can do the actual process pretty easily in Excel. I'm newer to R and don't know how to translate my abilities in Excel to R.

My example table of Raw Data:

```
Date       Name     Valid   Population
1/4/2016    US      Yes     -100
1/4/2016    US      Yes     -1000
1/4/2016    Angola  Yes      400
1/5/2016    US      Yes      500
1/6/2016    Angola  Yes      300
1/7/2016    Japan   No      -100
1/8/2016    Japan   Yes     -500
1/8/2016    US      Yes      600
1/9/2016    Angola  Yes     -200
1/10/2016   US      Yes      800
```

This is what I want the my end result to be.
It should be a separate Data Frame which has new column headings and the Date column is now in sequential order and only contains unique values.

```
Date        US     Angola   Japan
1/4/2016    -1100   400     0
1/5/2016    -600    400     0
1/6/2016    -600    700     0
1/7/2016    -600    700     0
1/8/2016     0      700    -500
1/9/2016     0      500    -500
1/10/2016    800    500    -500
```

It would be great for anyone to help me achieve the desired table.

Sincerely,
Riddler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the input `DF` is as in the note at the end, we convert the `Date` column to `"Date"` class, use `xtabs` to create the wide form matrix `x` with `Population` summations in each `Date`/`Name` cell, apply `cumsum` to each column giving matrix `a` and then either just use `a` or optionally convert `a` to a data frame.  No packages are used.

```
DF$Date <- as.Date(DF$Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")

x <- xtabs(Population ~ Date + Name, DF)
a <- apply(x, 2, cumsum)
data.frame(Date = as.Date(rownames(a)), a, row.names = NULL)
```

giving:

```
        Date Angola Japan    US
1 2016-01-04    400     0 -1100
2 2016-01-05    400     0  -600
3 2016-01-06    700     0  -600
4 2016-01-07    700  -100  -600
5 2016-01-08    700  -600     0
6 2016-01-09    500  -600     0
7 2016-01-10    500  -600   800
```

**Note:** We define the input `DF` reproducibly as:

```
Lines <- "Date       Name     Valid   Population
1/4/2016    US      Yes     -100
1/4/2016    US      Yes     -1000
1/4/2016    Angola  Yes      400
1/5/2016    US      Yes      500
1/6/2016    Angola  Yes      300
1/7/2016    Japan   No      -100
1/8/2016    Japan   Yes     -500
1/8/2016    US      Yes      600
1/9/2016    Angola  Yes     -200
1/10/2016   US      Yes      800"

DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks for the reply. It worked perfectly. Now that takes care of one of my biggest portions of my project. I never knew about this xtabs function. Still not completely sure what it actually does... but it works.